# svcutil.exe client proxy and fault contract

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe, faultcontract

Is it possible to have fault contract information included in my svcutil.exe generated client c# proxy code?
I mean, if a web service method is marked with `FaultContractAttribute`, I want it's type argument to be mentioned in comments to client proxy's method, so that when I use it, i could see what exceptions have to be catched.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/